# Is it possible to use a formula to find if there is more than one occurrence of a date within an excel table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am attempting to make a calendar in excel that will show when people are out of the office that will highlight the calendar based off the inputs each person makes to the corresponding table. The problem I am running into is how to highlight a cell in the calendar when two or more people are out of the office on that day, the closest I can get is only showing the highlighting for one person or the other, not both.

For example, if person A and person C are both out of the office on 6/1/2019, I would like for that date to show up in a different color than either of the headers for person A or C.

Also, this calendar will be stored in a shared location that automatically disables the use of macros, so I am only able to use formulas and conditional formatting.  Thanks for any suggestions! [image: Out of Office Calendar]

Comment: Can you show what you are doing right now?

Comment: Also are you sure that macros will be disabled? that 'manipulate slider to select desired year' looks a lot like its powered with a macro...

Comment: Right now I am using the following conditional formats to highlight cells: =VLOOKUP(B2,$AJ$4:$AJ$31,1,FALSE) And yes, I am positive that macros are disabled. The slider does not actually work, it is from a previous calendar that allowed macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is to have a separate list in which you have a list of dates and the number of occurrence of each date. Then you should add a conditional-formatting that colors dates with count of more than 1 and change the conditional-formatting of each person and check this count, if it is 1, then you apply the format.

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of this, great solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional formating with the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF($AJ$2:$AS$31,AJ2)>1
```

and apply it to `AJ2:AS31`